# On refresh, Angular app says "Template error: Can't bind to 'myprop' since it isn't a known property of 'app-my-component'"

Tags: angular

In my simple Angular app, I have this code in `app.component.html`

```
<app-my-component [myProp]="thepropvar"></app-my-component>
```

It works when I do `ng serve --aot`, but when I make a change, it refreshes, and puts this error in the console:

```
core.js:4002 ERROR Error: Template error: Can't bind to 'myprop' since it isn't a known property of 'app-my-component'
```

It completely works until I modify something, such as putting `<p>Poo</p>` on the page.

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: what does my-component look like? does it have an @Input for myProp? and is it the correct data type?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a `myprop` (in lowercase) in your code.

Comment: Yes there's an @Input for myprop. It works fine on first run. It fails on rerun

Comment: On further study, it appears the problem goes away when I don't use `--aot`. Hmmm... why would that be ?

Comment: Can you show your component's declaration and input?